# How to create a div which is skewed on one side

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

There would be some text inside the div and I should be able to set the height and width of div to auto so that it would resize according to text inside.
The skew angle would be 45*

[image]

Comment: Check https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/#trapezoid

Comment: You need to use :after. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lyqjkkbo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

**CSS**

```
.bar {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #BC5859;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative
}

.bar:before {
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    border-left: 100px solid #BC5859;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 0px;
    right: -100px;
    top:0;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/hsk9fz87/8/)**